# Find the sum of all values of $a$ satisfying that there exist positive integers $a,b$ satisfying $(a-b) \sqrt{ab}=2016$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the sum of all values of $a$ satisfying that there exist positive integers $a,b$ satisfying $$(a-b) \sqrt{ab}=2016$$

my try

let $a= x^2$  , $b= y^2$ $\to$ $(a-b) \sqrt{ab}$=$(x^2-y^2)(xy)=2016$

is this approach appropriate for this problem ? please elaborate your help

Comment: In your try you assume $a$ and $b$ are squares?

Comment: @Shuri2060 yes , to get rid of sqrt

Comment: That only handles some of the possible cases, though. Edit: I'd presumed $a,b$ are integers

Comment: are $a$ and $b$ integers?

Comment: Are $a,b$ meant to be integers?

Comment: $a , b$  positive integers

Comment: We just need $ab$ to be perfect square, don't need each to square separately.  If $a=r^2c,b=s^2c,$  $$2016=rsc^2(r^2-s^2)$$

Comment: It'd be probably more helpful to include the prime factorization of $2016=2^5 \times 3^2 \times 7$

Comment: We know $(a-b)$ is an integer. Therefore $\sqrt{ab}$ must be a rational. We also know $ab$ is an integer. The square roots of integers are either integer or irrational. Therefore $\sqrt{ab}$ must be an integer. For that to happen, $ab$ must only contain square factors - ie. its prime factorization must be of the form $\prod p_i^{2\alpha_i}$. Hence $a$ and $b$ must be in the forms suggested above by @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @prayersmith At which point in particular? You now know $2016=2^5 \times 3^2 \times 7=rsc^2(r^2-s^2)$ for some positive integers $c,r,s$. You just need to figure out how to split the factorization up. Perhaps think about the possibilities for $c^2$? Or $r^2-s^2$? I'm not sure myself, but these are some ideas

Comment: The form of the question suggests it's a competition problem. It would be good if you were to cite the source.

Comment: I thought as much, all I can think of is ways to do the brute force faster, but cannot solve the general Diophantine equation :(

Comment: Is this the result? $81+128=209$

Comment: Please, where did you find this problem? If you tell this, then it would help everyone.

Answer (score 4):

A start of a solution.

The prime factorization of $2016$ is $2^5\cdot3^2\cdot7$.

In order for $\sqrt{ab}$ to be a integer, both $a$ and $b$ must be multiples of squares and the same factors, i.e. $a=zx^2,b=zy^2, x>y$. Thus:
$$(a-b)\sqrt{ab}=z^2(x^2-y^2)xy = 2016$$

Use the fact that *if neither of two numbers is divisible by 3, the difference of their squares must be*. Thus, $z$ can not be a multiple of $3$, and since it cannot be a multiple of $7$, it must be one of $1,2,4$. 
So now we must solve:
$$(x^2-y^2)xy = 2016 = 2^5\cdot 3^2\cdot7$$
$$(x^2-y^2)xy = 504  = 2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot7$$
$$(x^2-y^2)xy = 126  = 2^1\cdot 3^2\cdot7$$

Comment: I forgot about $a^2 \equiv 1$ for $a \not\equiv 0 \mod 3$. But I was wondering why you didn't discount $z = 4$? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @mdave16 - You can indeed discard $z=4$ after some additional work.

Comment: Ive thought hard about what the extra work could be, could you detail the step ive missed? what am i missing?

Answer (score 4):

$$\text{Find} \;\sum_{(a,b) \in S}a 
  \qquad \text{where} \qquad
  S=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb Z^+ : (a-b)\sqrt{ab}=2016\}$$

Let $(a,b) \in S$ and let $x = \sqrt{ab}$. Then $(a-b) = \dfrac{2016}{x}$.

So

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
  a = \sqrt{ab + \frac 14(a-b)^2} + \frac 12(a-b) \\
  b = \sqrt{ab + \frac 14(a-b)^2} - \frac 12(a-b) \\
\end{array}
\right\}
\implies
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
  a = \sqrt{x^2 + \dfrac{1008^2}{x^2}} + \dfrac{1008}{x} \\
  b = \sqrt{x^2 + \dfrac{1008^2}{x^2}} - \dfrac{1008}{x} \\
\end{array}
\right\}$$

We need to solve $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ where $xy = 1008$.

For now, because of symmetry, we can assume $x < y$.  Then the possibilities for $x$ are
$$x \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24, 28\}$$

### Working mod 11.

The quadratic residues modulo $11$ are

\begin{array}{|c|cccccc|}
\hline
   x   & 0 & 1,10 & 2,9 & 3,8 & 4,7 & 5,6 \\
   x^2 & 0 & 1    & 4   & 9   & 5   & 3 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Since $xy = 1008 = 7 = 18 = 29 = 40 = 51 = 62 = 73 = 84 = 95 \pmod{11}$, the possibilities for $x,y$ (accounting for $x, y$ symmetry) are

\begin{array}{|c|ccccc|}
\hline
   x         & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  & 5 \\
   y         & 7 & 9 & 6 & 10 & 8 \\
   x^2 + y^2 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 6  & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

We find $x \pmod{11} \in \{3,5,6,8\}$.
This whittles the list down to 
$$x \in \{3, 6, 8, 14, 16, 28\}$$

### Working mod 13.

The quadratic residues modulo $13$ are

\begin{array}{|c|cccccc|}
\hline
   x   & 0 & 1,12 & 2,11 & 3,10 & 4,9 & 5,8 & 6,7 \\
   x^2 & 0 & 1    & 4    & 9    & 3   & 12  & 10 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Since $xy = 1008 = 7 = 20 = 33 = 46 = 59 = 72 = 85 = 98 \pmod{13}$,
the possibilities for $x,y$ (accounting for $x, y$ symmetry) are

\begin{array}{|c|ccccc|}
\hline
         x & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4 & 6  & 8\\
         y & 7  & 10 & 11 & 5 & 12 & 9\\
   x^2+y^2 & 11 & 0  & 0  & 2 & 11 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{array}

We find $x \pmod{13} \in \{ 2, 3, 10, 11 \}$ This whittles the list down to 
$$x \in \{3, 16, 28\}$$

We compute $x, y,$ and $z$.

\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y=\dfrac{1008}{x} & z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
\hline
                 3 &             336 & 336.0133926 \\
   \color{red}{16} & \color{red}{63} & \color{red}{65} \\
                28 &              36 & 45.607017 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Hence

\begin{array}{ccc|cc|c}
   x & y=\frac{1008}{x} 
     & z=\sqrt{x^2+\left(\frac{1008}{x}\right)^2} 
     & a=z+y & b=z-y & (a-b)\sqrt{ab} \\
\hline
   16 & 63 & 65 & 128 & 2 & 2016 \\
   63 & 16 & 65 & 81 & 49 & 2016 \\
\hline
\end{array}

So $\sum_{(a,b)\in S}a  = 128 + 81 = 209$

Comment: Very elegant, if it wasn't for the 15 cases we had to check. Do you think we could bring this number down?

Answer (score 3):

$$(a-b)\sqrt{ab}=2016\tag1$$

Since $a-b$ is a positive integer, $\sqrt{ab}$ is a positive rational number. Let $\sqrt{ab}=\dfrac mn$ where $m,n$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$, from which we have $ab=\dfrac{m^2}{n^2}$. The LHS is an integer, so is the RHS, from which we have to have $n=1$.

Since both $a-b$ and $\sqrt{ab}$ are positive integers, we can set $a-b=s,ab=t^2$ where $s,t$ are positive integers such that $st=2016$.

Since $a=s+b,t=\dfrac{2016}{s}$, we have
$$ab=t^2\implies (s+b)b=\left(\dfrac{2016}{s}\right)^2\implies b=\dfrac{-s^2+\sqrt{D}}{2s}$$
where $D=s^4+ 2^{12}\cdot 3^4\cdot 7^2$.

Since $2016=2^5\times 3^2\times 7^1$, let $s=2^i\cdot 3^j\cdot 7^k$ where $i,j,k$ are non-negative integers such that $0\le i\le 5,0\le j\le 2$ and $0\le k\le 1$.

Since $s$ is a positive divisor of $2016$, there are $(5+1)(2+1)(1+1)=36$ cases to consider, but we don't need to check if $\sqrt D$ is an integer for $36$ distinct $s$ respectively.

Now,
$$\small\begin{align}\sqrt D&=\sqrt{s^4+ 2^{12}\cdot 3^4\cdot 7^2}\\\\&=\sqrt{2^{4i}\cdot 3^{4j}\cdot 7^{4k}+2^{12}\cdot 3^4\cdot 7^2}\\\\&=\sqrt{2^{\min(4i,12)} 3^{\min(4j,4)} 7^{\min(4k,2)}(2^{4i-\min(4i,12)} 3^{4j-\min(4j,4)} 7^{4k-\min(4k,2)}+2^{12-\min(4i,12)} 3^{4-\min(4j,4)} 7^{2-\min(4k,2)})}\\\\&=2^{\min(2i,6)} 3^{\min(2j,2)} 7^{\min(2k,1)}\sqrt{2^{4i-\min(4i,12)} 3^{4j-\min(4j,4)} 7^{4k-\min(4k,2)}+2^{12-\min(4i,12)} 3^{4-\min(4j,4)} 7^{2-\min(4k,2)}}\end{align}$$
Note here that 
$$(4i-\min(4i,12))(12-\min(4i,12))=0$$
$$(4j-\min(4j,4))(4-\min(4j,4))=0$$
$$(4k-\min(4k,2))(2-\min(4k,2))=0$$
from which we see that $\sqrt D$ is of the form either
$$u\sqrt{1+v^2},\quad u\sqrt{3^4+(7v)^2},\quad u\sqrt{7^2+(2^{2w}\cdot 3^z)^2},\quad u\sqrt{2^{4v}+3^w\cdot 7^z}$$
where $u,v$ are positive integers, and $w,z$ are non-negative integers.

We can easily see that the first three forms cannot be an integer.

- $\sqrt  D=u\sqrt{1+v^2}$ is not an integer since $1+y^2=x^2\iff (x-y)(x+y)=1$ has no positive integer solutions.
- $\sqrt D=u\sqrt{3^4+(7v)^2}$ is not an integer since the positive integer solutions for $3^4+y^2=x^2\iff (x-y)(x+y)=3^4$ are $(x-y,x+y)=(1,3^4),(3,3^3)$, i.e. $(x,y)=(41,40),(15,12)$, from which there are no $v$ such that $7v=40,12$.
- $\sqrt D=u\sqrt{7^2+(2^{2w}\cdot 3^z)^2}$ is not an integer since the positive integer solution for $7^2+y^2=x^2\iff (x-y)(x+y)=7^2$ is $(x-y,x+y)=(1,7^2)$, i.e. $(x,y)=(25,24)$, from which there is no $(w,z)$ such that $2^{2w}\cdot 3^z=24$.
- For the form $\sqrt D=u\sqrt{2^4+3^w\cdot 7^z}$, we have $(i,j,k)=(4,0,0),(2,2,1)$. In either case, $\sqrt D$ is of the form $u\sqrt{2^4+3^4\cdot 7^2}=u\sqrt{3985}=u\sqrt{5\times 797}$ which is not an integer where $797$ is a prime.
- For the form $\sqrt D=u\sqrt{2^8+3^w\cdot 7^z}$, we have $(i,j,k)=(5,0,0),(1,2,1)$. In either case, $\sqrt{D}$ is of the form $u\sqrt{2^8+3^4\cdot 7^2}=65u$ which is an integer, which gives $(a,b)=(81,49),(128,2)$ respectively.
- For the form $\sqrt D=u\sqrt{2^{12}+3^w\cdot 7^z}$, we have $(i,j,k)=(0,2,1)$. In this case, $\sqrt D$ is of the form $u\sqrt{2^{12}+3^4\cdot 7^2}=u\sqrt{8065}=u\sqrt{5\times 1613}$ which is not an integer where $1613$ is a prime.

Since the solutions for $(1)$ are $(a,b)=(81,49),(128,2)$, the answer is
$$81+128=\color{red}{209}$$

Comment: $n=1$ doesn't follow - it could be that $a-b$ is a multiple of $n^2$

Comment: @nbubis: The point is $\gcd(m,n)=1$. I set $\sqrt{ab}=\frac mn$ where $m,n$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$. So, I think that we have to have $n=1$ when we have $ab=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$ whose LHS is an integer. Am I mistaken? What I was trying to say in that part was $\sqrt{ab}$ is a positive integer.

Comment: You are correct, but I think the logic could be explained better.

Comment: @nbubis: Yeah, I have to say I agree with you.